# VS 2012 Private NuGet Server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget-server

I followed the instructions from the NuGet web site (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) on how to create a NuGet server.

I got the web site deployed and the main page shows, but when I click on the Packages link I get

> Could not load file or assembly 'Elmah' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The only changes I made to the web.config was remove an extra compilation tag (It put tags with 4.5 and 4.0 in the file) and add an API key.

I am using VS 2012 RC with .net 4.5.  NOTE:  I tried the exact same thing in VS 2010 and it works, so mabey this process is not ready for VS 2012 yet?  Or do I have to do something manually to get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for VS2012, but if you're interested in hosting your own feed locally you can also use [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget/download).

Comment: Well, I got everything working in the end, just that I had to use VS 2010 instead of 2012.  It's only RC, so maybe they are still missing someting in the NuGet.Server package.

Comment: www.myget.org is a possibility as well

Comment: I really like NuPeek. It provides not only a NuGet feed, but also a Symbol Server, so that you can still debug into your local packages. It's Open Source.